# Run Process throws error "expected at least 1 non-keyword argument, got 0"

Tags: process, robotframework

I tried to use "Run Process" keyword from Process library in Robot Framework script to run a perl script with arguments in a folder having different path with the current folder.

```
Run Process  ./post.pl arg1 arg2   shell=True    cwd=/a/b/c
```

When it is run, it throws an error:

```
Keyword 'Process.Run Process' expected at least 1 non-keyword argument, got 0.
```

Does anyone know what might cause this and how to resolve it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this is the only problem, but it appears you only have one space between `./post.pl`, `arg1`, and `arg2`. You need two spaces between each.

Comment: as @BryanOakley stated, this should be as follows:
  

`Run Process<space><space>./post.pl<space><space>arg1<space><space>arg2<space><space>shell=True<space><space>cwd=/a/b/c`

Comment: I did use one space between post.pl, arg1, and arg2, and three spaces before shell=True and cwd=/a/b/c. But it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 5):

This problem can occur when `arg1` or `arg2` contain symbols that Robot Framework itself recognises. Make sure you escape those with a backslash.

For example, see the following command:

```
curl <args> "<url>/download?job=<name>"
```

This will result in "Keyword 'Process.Run Process' expected at least 1 non-keyword argument, got 0." The issue is, that Robot Framework thinks the `=` is an assignment, so you need to escape it:

```
curl <args> "<url>/download?job\=<name>"
```

Note the `job\=<name>` instead of `job=name`. There is no need to add multiple spaces between a command and its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in such cases the issue is with the spaces - as observed in similar instances my end. What I follow hence, is maintaining same spaces, between robot-framework command and the argument/command, and then the same in the following arguments w.r.t. the robot-framework commands.

i.e.

```
Run Process    ./post.pl arg1 arg2    shell=True    cwd=/a/b/c
```

Equal spaces gap each (~4 in above case, for example). But excluding `./post.pl arg1 arg2`

If this doesn't resolve, then typically would be interesting to note the expanded version of the `arg1` and `arg2` in use there. Try executing by direct substitution, to get the just right spaced/indented usage in your context.